# How to set Email Opt Out field as checked for Particular Profile?

Tags: community, administration, contact, admin

Set Email Opt Out field as true for only one profile.for remaining profiles set as unchecked.How to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using record types. Specify your record types and what picklist values they will display and then assign the record type/s to your profiles.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your suggestion,We can not do using Record types.Email Opt Out filed is check box.

Comment: I think there is no direct method to do this. Please refer the link. This is somewhat similar to your requirement 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=0873000000078qkAAA

Comment: Do you want to restrict users from Checking Email Opt Field?